# Can a kid's taste preferences be affected by the mother consuming them during pregnancy?

Tags: food, pregnancy

Can a person alter what foods their kid will like in the future by consuming them during pregnancy?

Comment: Check out this TED Talk! http://ecochildsplay.com/2011/11/30/ted-talks-annie-murphy-paul-what-we-learn-before-were-born/

Comment: My mother ate a lot of shellfish during pregnancy, which I have never particularly cared for and now avoid for religious reasons.  So, no guarantee that what she eats will be what your kid eats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can, according to [this article from livestrong.com](http://www.livestrong.com/article/555283-pregnancy-cravings-food-preferences-in-children/), though [the study this statement is based on](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1343304) has only been done on rats

> What you may not consider is that the foods you eat while pregnant
>   might influence the tastes your child prefers after he is born. A
>   healthy diet throughout your pregnancy supports your unborn baby's
>   growth and development, but when you fill up on junk food, you might
>   shape his preference for unhealthy foods later in life.

Personally, I'm skeptical you can have much control over this during pregnancy - a lot of what their tastes will be form during the first year, and what's important is not specifically what they eat, but whether it is balanced and nutritious.  [This article](http://www.justmommies.com/articles/healthy-eating-baby.shtml) has a good list of tips to help infants/toddlers develop good eating habits.

Answer (score 2):

During pregnancy it would be wise to 'feed' your wife exactly what she wants. In all seriousness though, my own observation is that this is a myth. My wife likes all sorts of food that our children wont eat. Also each child has their own preferences even though she ate pretty much the same things throughout both pregnancies.